# Where can I get historic data series of Bitcoin prices for over a year and 5 minute intervals?

Tags: historical-trade-data

I am looking to get OHLC data of BTC/USD for over a year and the time intervals that I am interested in are 5 minutes. Is there any API (or website with csv files) that can download this data from? Free or paid.